Is this incorrect usage of だからと言って？
I'm going through the 新完全マスターN1: 文法, and the following question is given:

長期入院中（　）、わたしにも選挙権があるのだ。
1 だからといって　２　にかかわらず　３　と思いきや　４　といえども

The bolded 4: といえども is what the book says is the correct answer. However, I initially thought the answer was 1. Can someone explain why 1 is incorrect? This HiNative post says that だからといって is usually followed with a negative phrase, but I found conflicting opinions on chiebukuro. So are both ok, or is 4 the only correct answer here?

Can someone explain why 1 is incorrect? 「長期入院中だからといって、私にも選挙権があるのだ。」Just because I'm in the hospital, I also have the right to vote って、英語ではおかしくないんですか？

@chocolate That makes a lot of sense. So だからといって can be directly translated to "just because"?

I think it can. だからといって is usually used in the structure 「～～だからといって…（というわけでは・とは限らetc）ない」 "Just because~~, it doesn't mean ..."

It's true that Aだからといって usually expects a phrase like Bというわけではない, Bということにはならない, or Bとはいえない, and I believe the exam is testing whether you have this knowledge. If passing the exam is your priority, I think it's best to regard this as a "rule". (Similarly, at least for English exam purposes, it's safe to assume that "Just because A" at the beginning of a sentence is always followed by "doesn't mean B".)
However, in reality...

✅長期入院中だからといって、わたしに選挙権がないわけではないのだ。
✅長期入院中だからといっても、わたしにも選挙権があるのだ。
❓長期入院中だからといって、わたしにも選挙権があるのだ。

Sentences 1 and 2 are 100% correct. Sentence 3 is tricky; while I understand that it would be marked as incorrect in an exam, if this sentence appeared in a real novel, few people would consider it wrong or unnatural. In most cases, it would simply be interpreted as a little uncommon or rhetorical version of Sentence 2.
